# Find position and get before and after?

Tags: php

```
$x = "P-29042011386693";
$array = "P-28042011135870,P-28042011132333,P-28042011384621,P-29042011386693,P-29042011384190,P-29042011388434,P-29042011382454,P-29042011385512,P-29042011383902";
$array = explode(",", $array);
$count = count($array);
$search = array_search($x, $array);

if (($search > 0) && ($search < $count)){
    $before = $array[$search-1];
    $after = $array[$search+1];
}elseif ($search == 0){
    $before = NULL;
    $after = $array[1];
}elseif ($search == $count){
    $before = $array[$count-1];
    $after = NULL;
}
```

What is the best way to detect the value before $x and the value after $x, and display $before or $after as blank if there is no result before/after $x?

So if $x was P-29042011383902 - $after would be blank and $before would be P-29042011385512

If $x was P-28042011135870 $before would be blank and $after would be P-28042011132333

Is my code above right?

Comment: Is that data all in one column in one row or is that a representation of the column data for a result set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$search = array_search($x, $array);
if (false === $search) {
    throw new Exception('Not found', 404);
}
$before = isset($array[$search - 1]) ? $array[$search - 1] : null;
$after  = isset($array[$search + 1]) ? $array[$search + 1] : null;
```

Comment: @Kyle I've updated my answer though didn't have to change much, mainly removed the space after the comma in the delimiter used in `explode()`

Comment: Perfect, Phil - along the lines of what I was doing but a little shorter code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

$eachone = explode (" ,", $row);

6 is $eachone[6]

5 is $eachone[6-1]

If i understood the question, that's it.

With new information:

The example at php.net is this:

```
$str = "Hello Friend"; 
$arr1 = str_split($str); and you get an array like this

Array
(
    [0] => H[1] => e
    [2] => l
    [3] => l
    [4] => o
    [5] =>
    [6] => F
    [7] => r
    [8] => i
    [9] => e
    [10] => n
    [11] => d
)
```

Comment: Yes, is the same but you must "explode" in other way if isn't delimited with "," like you said. Modified answer.